# How to dynamically set a value in option:contains in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a variable which i get from the user dynamically:

```
var prodlineselec=$( "tr" ).last().children("td").find('#prodLine :selected').text();
```

I now want to set this variable in the next row picklist value:

Now, this works:

```
$("tr").last().children('td').find('option:contains("Automotive")').attr("selected",true);
```

But when I try to do this dynamically it gives me nothing:

```
$("tr").last().children('td').find('option:contains(""+prodlineselec+"")').attr("selected",true);
```

please suggest!

Comment: `$('#prodLine :selected').text();` should give you the same as IDs have to be unique. And it should be `('option:contains("'+prodlineselec+'")') ` (you aren't escaping the single quotes of the `.find`.

Comment: Thanks!! that worked. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've a quotes issue replace this part :

```
.find('option:contains(""+prodlineselec+"")')
_______________________^^_______________^^
```

By :

```
.find('option:contains("'+prodlineselec+'")')
```

Note the duplicated double quotes `""`.

Full statement will be :

```
$("tr").last()
       .children('td')
       .find('option:contains("'+prodlineselec+'")')
       .attr("selected",true);
```

Hope this helps.